# Как удалить скобки у количества товаров Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Добавляю количество товара через get_cart, как убрать скобки у цифры на выходе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
    <div class="s-header__basket-wr woocommerce">
    <?php
    global $woocommerce; ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ?>" class="basket-btn basket-btn_fixed-xs">
        
        <span class="basket-btn__counter">(<?php
         echo count( WC()->cart->get_cart() );
         
         ?>)</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Это шутка? у вас идет тег <span> '(' php запрос ')' </span>  Вы вручную уберите внутри тега скобки.

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я прощелкал) утро совсем раннее было)

Comment: ludin, и я подумал что не выспался xD

Comment: Хотя нет) все равно оставляет скобки, udhouse.ru

Comment: Если вы выгружаете из БД, смотрите на типы которые запрашиваете и какие в базе. Например в MSSQL если выставить число(значение) таблицы по умолчанию оно имеет вид - ((0)). Не рискну точно утверждать, но думаю выгружая число вы имеете дело с переопределением типов и он вам выдает как строку

Comment: get_cart() - возвращает массив - поэтому у вас там скобки, выводите как элемент массива, а не просто массив

Comment: да я уже понял, спасибо, не правильно выводил)

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится, чтобы вывести количество товаров в корзине Woocommerce, можно просто вставить вот такой код

```
<span class="btn__cart"><?php echo $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count ?></span>
```

по классу можно стилизовать цифру как нужно